# ¿Ayuda mi pdf se genera sin problemas pero al agregar un condicional deja de funcionar?

Tags: php, mariadb, fpdf

Hola estoy dando permisos a mi sistema, genero un pdf haciendo consultas  a una base datos, funciona perfecto incluso al agregar el if y validar el inicio de sesion y el nivel de privilegio del usario, pero en el momento en el que uso el else me sale el error 500 en mi host, el codigo funciona y protege usando solo el if es realmente necesario el uso de else?

```
<?php
include_once 'resource/session.php';
include_once 'resource/Database.php';
include_once 'resource/utilities.php';
include_once 'partials/parseProfile.php';
include'fpdf/fpdf.php';

setlocale(LC_TIME,"es_ES");

 if(!(isset($_SESSION['username'])) || !$_SESSION['editar_coa'] == 1 ){

     echo"No tienes permisos para ver el coa";
 } 


    else{

// aqui van el codigo que genera mi pdf
$pdf->Output();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta ver en el archivo de log de tu servidor web, o bien habilita que se muestren los errores en el cliente con algo como:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

De igual modo si es un error fatal puede que no se muestre en el browser, la opción más segura es el log de errores de tu servidor web.

Saludos